# Unix - circular shift of rows and columns in a file

Tags: unix, awk

Given a file that contains something like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
a b c d
e f g h
```

Is there any unix command that I could use to circular shift the rows and coluns?

I am looking for something like say,

`circular_shift -r 2 <file>` (shift row by 2) to give :

```
a b c d
e f g h
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

and

`circular_shift -c 2 <file>` (shift column by 2) to give :

```
3 4 1 2
7 8 5 6
c d a b
g h e f
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using multidimensional arrays in `gawk`

> circular_shift.awk

```
{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i){d[NR][i]=$i}}
END{
    c=c%NF; r=r%NR
    for(i=1; i<=NR; ++i){
        nr = i + (i>r?0:NR) - r
        for(j=1; j<=NF; ++j){
            nc = j + (j>c?0:NF) - c
            printf d[nr][nc] (j!=NF?OFS:RS)
        }
    }
}
```

> awk -vr=2 -f circular_shift.awk file

```
a b c d
e f g h
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

> awk -vc=2 -f circular_shift.awk file

```
3 4 1 2
7 8 5 6
c d a b
g h e f
```

> awk -vr=2 -vc=2 -f circular_shift.awk file

```
c d a b
g h e f
3 4 1 2
7 8 5 6
```

Comment: `^1` Nice approach

Comment: Ended up using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Using awk for row shift processing the `file` twice:

```
$ awk -v r=2 'NR==FNR && FNR>r || NR>FNR && FNR<=r' file file
a b c d
e f g h
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Basically it prints records where `NR > r` on the first go and `NR <= r` on the second.

**Edit**: Version regarding records and fields:

```
$ awk -v r=1 -v c=1 '
NR==FNR && FNR>r || NR>FNR && FNR<=r {
    j=0;
    for(i=c+1;++j<=NF;i=(i<NF?i+1:1)){
        printf "%s%s",$i,(i==c?ORS:OFS)
    }
}
' foo foo
6 7 8 5
b c d a
f g h e
2 3 4 1
```

(Pretty much untested as I'm in a meeting... it fails at least for `c=0`)

Comment: This is nice! Just to note that this will work only for r<NR, it cannot do more than one cycle. Is it possible to do the column shift in the same way?

Comment: @VivekVK Not the same way, no. It would probably need a couple of `for`s.

Comment: To make it work for `r>NR` would require three iterations. On the first go get the `NR` on the second start printing from `NR%r` and on the third end there.

Comment: `^1` Nice one! James

Answer (score 3):

### Shifting Rows

You can use `head`, `tail` and the shell:

```
function circular_shift() {
    n=$1
    file=$2
    tail -n +"$((n+1))" "$file"
    head -n "$n" "$file"
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
circular_shift 2 <file>
```

One restriction. The above function just works for `n <= nlines(file)`. If you want to get rid of that restriction you need to know the length of the file in advance and use the modulo operator:

```
function circular_shift() {
    n=$1
    file=$2
    len="$(wc -l "$file"|cut -d" " -f1)"
    n=$((n%len))
    tail -n +"$((n+1))" "$file"
    head -n "$n" "$file"
}
```

Now try to call:

```
circular_shift 6 <file>
```

---

### Shifting Columns

For the column shift I would use `awk`:

*column-shift.awk*

```
{
    n = n % NF
    c = 1

    for(i=NF-n+1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[c++] = $i
    }

    for(i=1; i<NF-n+1; i++) {
        a[c++] = $i
    }

    for(i=1; i<c; i++) {
        $i = a[i]
    }
}

print
```

Wrap it in a shell function:

```
function column_shift() {
    n="$1"
    file="$2"
    awk -v n="$n" -f column-shift.awk "$file"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek V K, Try:
For moving the rows to a number up-wards.

```
awk -vcount=2 'NR>count{print;next} NR<=count{Q=Q?Q ORS $0:$0} END{print Q}'   Input_file
```

For shifting the fields, could you please try following:

```
awk -vcount=2 '{for(i=count+1;i<=NF;i++){Q=Q?Q FS $i:$i};for(j=1;j<=count;j++){P=P?P FS $j:$j};print Q FS P;Q=P=""}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v C=$1 -v R=$2 '
function PrintReverse () {
      if( ! R ) return

      for( i=1; i>=0; i--) {
         for( j=1; j<=R; j++) {
            #print "DEBUG:: i: "i " j:" j " i * R + j :" i * R + j  " lr:" lr
            print L[ i * R + j ]
            L[ i * R + j ] = ""
         }
      }
   }

   {
   if( C ) {
      # Reverse Column
      for ( i=1; i<=NF; i+=2*C) {
         for( j=0; j<C; j++) {
            #print "DEBUG:: i: "i " j:" j " NF:" NF
            tmp = $(i+j)
            $(i+j) = $(i+j+C)
            $(i+j+C) = tmp
            }
         }
      $1=$1
      }

   if ( R ) {
      # Line buffer
      lr = ( FNR - 1 ) % ( R * 2 ) + 1
      L[ lr] = $0
      }
    else print
   }

   lr >= ( R * 2) { PrintReverse() }

   END { if( lr < ( R * 2 )) PrintReverse() }
   ' YourFile
```

Will do both your reverse action

- R is the number of row, C the number of column to reverse.
- using 2 loop (1 loop inside another one) [not the fastest but the more explicit for understanding the concept ion this case)
- this is a buffer permutation for lines by loading line in a buffer of twice the number of Row and print 2 half content in reverse order
- this is a field swap for column permutation, it cycle by 2 * number of column swaping field content with field with index + number of column
- Row are treated after the buffer is feeded (in fact each R * 2 lines)
- column are treated at each line
- i add a test `( C )`, `( ! R )`, ... to allow single reverse (Row only or Column only)